# Ошибка при передача jintArray с помощью JNI

Tags: c++, kotlin, jni

Пишу приложение с помощью андроид студии, на Котлине с с++ вставками.
Присутствует нативная функция, которая должна возвращать c++ Int[] -> Kotlin Array:

```
cpp:

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL
Java_com_example_cppincludes_MainActivity_getData(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */){

    jintArray to_ret = env->NewIntArray(2);
    jint a[] = {10, 11};
    env->SetIntArrayRegion(to_ret,0,2,a);

    return(to_ret);
}

Kotlin:

external fun getData(): Array<Int>
...
test1_button.setOnClickListener {
    var a = getData()
}
```

Сборка проекта и запуск происходят успешно. После, по нажатию кнопки приложение вылетает с ошибкой:

`A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: attempt to return an instance of int[] from java.lang.Integer[] com.example.cppincludes.MainActivity.getData()`

В интернете передача массива чисел cpp->Kotlin описана именно так, однако данная ошибка появляется постоянно. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как ее исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array<Int>` это `Integer[]` в Java, а C функция возвращает `int[]` в Java, которому соответствует `IntArray` в котлин. Соответственно сигнатура должна быть

```
external fun getData(): IntArray
```

Comment: Благодарю! Я уже все типы на все возможные менял, никак не получалось, а это видимо забыл попробовать :)

Comment: Возник аналогичный вопрос. В котлиновском файле функция описана как `external fun getstr(): String`, что вроде бы является `Kotlin.String`.  Из с++ возвращаю `jstring`, что в свою очередь точно является `Java.lang.String`. И это заводит меня в тупик, ибо классы вроде _mapped_, но ошибка вылазит.

Comment: @AnonimYs `java.lang.String` маппится в `kotlin.String!`, то бишь с учетом потенциальной нулевости, так что оно должно работать

Comment: да, работает идеально, просто я полтора часа искал ошибку в методе, а она была в неправильном названии.